# Error while trying trying to run make command

Tags: makefile, macos-mojave, dyld, g77

I am trying to install a program and when I run make or make -f Makefile (following the installation instructions) I get the following output:

```
g77 -O5 -Wall  -c  prep_output.f  -o prep_output.o 
dyld: Symbol not found: ___keymgr_global
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/g77
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

make: *** [prep_output.o] Abort trap: 6
```

I am working on a macOS Mojave 10.14.6. Following some other proposed solutions in similar problems, I've already installed Command line tools in my Xcode but that didn't do the trick. Any suggestions please??

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I got rid of g77 and installed a compatible version of gcc (gcc8) through MacPorts. After running the make command I get the following:

```
g77 -O5 -Wall  -c  prep_output.f  -o prep_output.o 
make: g77: No such file or directory
make: *** [prep_output.o] Error 1
```

So I guess the program still needs the g77 setup?  This is the program btw ([http://www.cfht.hawaii.edu/~arnouts/LEPHARE/install.html]). Is there a way to rely to the gfortran compiler for building the program?

Thanks in advance

P.S. I noticed that when I install g77 I get the following error:

```
x usr/local/: Can't set user=0/group=0 for usr/local` 
`tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

However it still installs g77..

Comment: What version of 'g77' are you using ? can you share prep_output.f (the part, if any, that refers to __keymgr_global) ?

Comment: g77 3.4.  I'm afraid I don't know how to share prep_output.f... Could you guide me? Thanks. 
P.S. I noticed that when I install g77 I get the following error: 
`x usr/local/: Can't set user=0/group=0 for usr/local` 
`tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.`  However it still installs g77..

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that your installation of `g77` is broken.  This has nothing to do with `make` or the particular project you're trying to build, except inasmuch as the project is trying to use `g77` in the first place.  That is a bit surprising, actually, since `g77` has been obsolete for years (`gfortran` is the current GNU Fortran compiler), but I'm uncertain what exactly to expect from XCode in this area.

On the other hand, since the full path to the binary is `/usr/local/bin/g77`, I'm further inclined to think that you're not using XCode for this at all.  Possibly you've dumped a `g77` built on some other system into your `/usr/local/bin`, and it's not compatible with your Mojave system.

Your best bet is probably to

1. Get rid of your broken g77 installation.
2. Install Fink or MacPorts, or a similar project.
3. Install the Fink / MacPorts / whatever package for gfortran (maybe gcc-gfortran or similar in some of those) to get a working Fortran compiler.
4. Rely on that compiler to build your project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I followed your instructions and got rid of g77 and installed a compatible version of gcc (gcc8) through MacPorts. After running the make command I get the following:
`g77 -O5 -Wall  -c  prep_output.f  -o prep_output.o . 
make: g77: No such file or directory .
make: *** [prep_output.o] Error 1 .`
So I guess the program still needs the g77 setup? This is the program btw ([http://www.cfht.hawaii.edu/~arnouts/LEPHARE/install.html]). Is there a way to rely to the gfortran compiler for building the program?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @pchar, "rely[ing] on that compiler to build your project" may well be an active step.  That is, it may require you to modify the makefile to replace explicit references to `g77` with references to `gfortran`, or to take some other active measure to have `gfortran` used instead.  The question does not present enough detail for more specific instructions.